# Storing unspecified Protocol Buffer messages in another PB message?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I am trying to write an "extensible" file format using Google's Protocol Buffers (in Java). It should be possible for the API to read the data, and return a "container" message (of known type) containing some other messages, of unknown type (but which are know to the API caller).

What are the possible ways both in PB definitions and in the Java code, to do this?

One way that seems obvious is to store the class name implementing the unspecified message, along with a byte array containing the message data, in the "container" message. But I don't know how to create a message from it's class and the byte array, using reflection.

Another way is probably to use the "extension" mechanism, but I don't really get how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

If you have the correct Class name and a byte array, you can instantiate the corresponding `Builder` through reflection and then call the `mergeFrom(byte[])` method on it.

Comment: Thanks! "CLASS x = CLASS.newBuilder().mergeFrom(BYTES).build()" I'm going to wait a bit to see if someone can also tell me how to do it with extensions, before accepting your answer...

Answer (score 0):

We did something similar, but made a generic message such as the following:

```
message GenericMessage {
  required int32 id = 1;
  // further generic message headers

  message IntegerVariable {
    required string name = 1;
    optional int32 data = 2;
  }
  repeated IntegerVariable integerVars = 2;

  message IntegerArrayVariable {
    required string name = 1;
    repeated int32 data = 2;
    optional int32 length = 3;
  }
  repeated IntegerArrayVariable integerArrayVars = 3;

  message DoubleVariable {
    required string name = 1;
    optional double data = 2;
  }
  repeated DoubleVariable doubleVars = 4;

  ...

  message RawVariable {
    required string name = 1;
    optional bytes data = 2;
  }
  repeated RawVariable rawVars = x;
}
```

This allows you to use one buffer for many possible cases and still gives you the advantage of fast serialization/deserialization (no reflection required). The buffer can contain header variables that can be marked required or optional and a number of repeated payload variables. This allows the message to still be very small, despite that it's very generic.

If you create an additional layer to process these messages I'd suggest to process the message into a `HashMap<String, Object>` and return that to the application along with the header information. Between the applications you need to ensure that you get the name and the type correctly.

Comment: Regarding "fast serialization/deserialization (no reflection required)", the Reflection part should be minimal. Realistically, you only need to do it one time per Class that you encounter. The Builder you instantiate for that can be re-used. Unless every message is different, or the number of messages is very small, the overhead of the Reflection should be negligible.

Comment: That's true you can reuse it.